# How do you move a desktop icon offscreen?

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop, synctoy

I am using Microsoft's [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) in Windows 7 to do backups between several locations, including my desktop. Unfortunately, SyncToy stores metadata in [hidden .dat files](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synctoy/thread/8d3256d9-173f-404a-a68f-aca78382be15) that it leaves wherever it backs up to or from. I hate seeing this file on my desktop, but I don't want to hide hidden files. I am wondering if I could move it offscreen so I don't have to see it most of the time. I know this happens unintentionally occasionally, but I've never tried to do it intentionally. I am already at the maximum screen resolution so any solution that involves changing that probably won't work.

Comment: You're probably better off switching to a different Sync program that doesn't leave those types of files laying around. :)

Comment: I am open to that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Software suggestions are off-topic for SU buuuut here's a closed one that has suggestions: [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the desktop with the secondary mouse button to open the context menu, select `View` and then unmark `Align icons to the grid`. You can now drag the icons offscreen, but whenever the program creates new icons they'll be placed onscreen.

If you don't have anything on your desktop but those `.dat` icons you can also unmark `Show desktop icons` on that same menu to hide all icons on the desktop.

[image]

Image from [ebugg-i.com](http://tech.ebugg-i.com/2011/03/how-to-arrange-your-windows-desktop.html)

Comment: This basically works, I can move the icon so it is virtually offscreen--just a sliver visible when selected. I like having 'align icons to grid' on though. Is there any way to keep the icon offscreen even after you re-enable the setting?

Comment: The ideal would be to configure that program you are using to place the files elsewhere if possible, or use a different software entirely. There are some workarounds I can think of, but it all seems overcomplicated. You could [change the icon associated with `.dat`](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+icon+associated+with+extension) to nothing so only the filename would be displayed. You could get a second monitor, move the icons to the second monitor and then disable it thus getting back to your usual setup. The icons could come back, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is 7 years late but this is a possible clean solution. This is assuming you are starting your program via a shortcut on your desktop.

1. Create a folder on your desktop where you want all the .DAT files to go (or elsewhere);
2. If you check your SyncToy's shortcut properties you will see indications to a work directory. It *should* be your current desktop. Change it to point to the folder you created in point 1.

If the files **still** go on your desktop, then it's either hard-coded (rather dumb) or there is another setting somewhere. But I have a feeling this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software called fences. It adds the same function a cell phone has to switch between desktops (as when you slide your finger on the screen from side to side). You would just move that file to the desktop on the left or right.

See more http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/

See here for that specific function http://youtu.be/w9-xDAnfYlI?t=1m41s

Or you can swap to a software called [syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) for your backups